# JavaScript works in WordPress preview, not in the published post

Tags: javascript, wordpress, html

I have a JavaScript, which draws some stuff based on user input. I've put the link to the .js file in WordPress header, and I should put `<div id="drawstuff"></div>` where I want it to show up. So if I put it into a post, it works fine in the preview, but when I publish that post, there's only a note that my browser requires JavaScript :( Please help!

Comment: Are you getting any errors in the console?

Comment: If you're using Safari or Chrome, right click the page and select Inspect Element, then choose the Console tab. In Firefox, you could install [Firebug](http://getfirebug.com/), then right click the page and select Inspect Element, choose the Console tab. Refresh the page, see if there are any errors.

Comment: thanks!! found the error, a slash before destination folder was needed, otherwise it would append the folder to the post address.

Comment: Good work! The console is a wonderful tool.

Answer (score -1):

I had the same problem and the solutions was that I didn't have a / at the beginning of the links in the header.

Thanks!